# How to get current weather from android device?

Tags: android

I am developing an app, in this app how can get current weather from its device.

My questions:

1. How to get current weather from android device? or
2. How can get current weather free (no use any API), how to access device weather temperature?

Comment: Try using https://weatherdbi.herokuapp.com . It is free to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **weather** info you **will** need an API but if only some data interest you, you might just want to use the user's phone sensors. Assuming it is equiped which isn't guaranteed. Here is the official documentation of [Environment sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment) I hope this will help you with your problem.